# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable. I have tried various solution but nothing working so far

Tags: python, machine-learning, recommendation-engine

I am working on a problem and I got stuck. I am not able to understand how to access methods from other classes when they're in different files. I am keep getting same error- "module" object is not callable.

I have made a function for CFModel for a recommendation system and saved as CFModel.py.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

````py
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import merge
from keras.layers import Embedding, Reshape
from keras.models import Sequential

class CFModel(Sequential):

    def __init__(self, n_users, m_items, k_factors, **kwargs):
        P = Sequential()
        P.add(Embedding(n_users, k_factors, input_length=1))
        P.add(Reshape((k_factors,)))
        Q = Sequential()
        Q.add(Embedding(m_items, k_factors, input_length=1))
        Q.add(Reshape((k_factors,)))

        super().__init__()
        #super(CFModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add(merge([P, Q], mode='dot', dot_axes=1))
    def rate(self, user_id, recipe_id):
        return self.predict([np.array([customer_id]), np.array([recipe_id])])[0][0]```

 ** And I am using it here **  

from CFModel import CFModel
model = CFModel(max_userid, max_recipeid, K_FACTORS)
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adamax')



Full Error log
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-90d66803fcfe> in <module>
      1 from CFModel import CFModel
----> 2 model = CFModel(max_userid, max_recipeid, K_FACTORS)
      3 model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adamax')

~/CFModel.py in __init__(self, n_users, m_items, k_factors, **kwargs)
     27 
     28         super(CFModel, self).__init__(**kwargs)
---> 29         self.add(merge([P, Q], mode='dot', dot_axes=1))
     30 
     31         # The Merge layer takes the dot product of user and movie latent factor vectors to return the corresponding rating.

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
````

Comment: You need to include full error messages, full tracebacks.

Comment: Please mind the case sensitivity. Your class is `CFmodel` (with lower case m). Thus, your import statement should be `from CFModel import CFmodel`.

Comment: @afsharov Sorry, its my mistake while typing it here. They both are in capital letters and identical.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I just added the full error log. Thank you

Comment: It looks like merge is a module, not a function.

Comment: This is old code for earlier versions of Keras, see the duplicate answer on how to update your code (merge is now a module and not a function).